# Use Ubuntu with wifi-adaper AWUS036ach - rtl8812au

Tags: wifi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, usb-device, realtek

Every road I follow leeds to:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
```

Like this:

```
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
[sudo] password for pelle:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

This I can not understand even though it seems I already have this version.

```
$ uname -r
    5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

Why Is the system not finding the package-version I already have?

What I want is to make Ubuntu to work with my wifi-adaper AWUS036ach - rtl8812au. Install driver, locate device with lsusb, connect with airmon-ng for example, put it in monitor-mode and so on. (In VMware and Kali Linux I got it fine). But I want to go over to Ubuntu.

Last two days I worked this https://github.com/morrownr/8812au-20210629 one over and over and it fails when I come to installing kernel-headers. What I get is:

```
sudo apt install kernel-headers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kernel-headers
```

Tried with dozens of different content in the repositories sources.list and nothing changes.

build-essential is already the newest version.

In many google-searches it suggests that the kernel should be updated, tried hundreds of advices and it always end in not finding packages etc.

This one is also not working

```
$ sudo apt install ip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ip
```

So how do I fix the issue with the headers? From what I understand the solution is depending on that.. ? Hope my question make sense, understand if this looks totally confused :-)
Im expert in welding and steelconstructions, but in this Im totaly newborn and lost :-D

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$ uname -r
5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

Installed from Microsoft Store

On Lenovo laptop windows 10
Windows subsystem for Linux - activated
Virtual machine platform - activated

Comment: Btw, can not find usb-devices with lsusb, only this: $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub and only lo and eth0 with ip a